# Volatility of Option

Tags: volatility, black-scholes

I hope I'm asking this at the right place.

This pertains to actuarial exam MFE/3F on Financial Economics. If $\sigma$ is "volatility" and $\Omega$ the elasticity of the stock, one formula that is taught in this course is

$$\sigma_{\text{option}} = \sigma_{\text{stock}} \cdot  |\Omega|\text{,}$$

where "option" means a call or a put.

[Finan (Proposition 31.1, pp. 234-235)](http://faculty.atu.edu/mfinan/actuarieshall/DFEM.pdf) proves this statement.

My question is, does this formula make an implicit assumption that the Black-Scholes assumptions have to hold?

Comment: Can you provide more info about this formula? Is Ω the option gearing (or leverage)?

Comment: I haven't heard of those terms before, but I can tell you that $\Omega = \dfrac{\Delta S_0}{C}$, where $C$ is the call price, $S_0$ is the initial stock price, and $\Delta = \dfrac{\partial C}{\partial S_0}$, the option Greek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From  the definitions and the proof given in the paper you only need a risk neutral measure and the possibility to hedge.

The assumptions you need to make are the absence of arbitrage opportunities (AOA) and the market completeness.

You also work with a constant volatility. I think the result can be generalized to non-constant volatility. There is still an embeded assumption we often forget: the existence of a volatility. The use of a given model will guarantee the existence of the vol,  But no need of a bs model.

Comment: ...which then basically sums up most B-S assumptions ;-)

Comment: The calculation are made with bs, but it shoul work with time varying r and sigma, whitout brownian motion.

Comment: yes as long as you have deterministic r and sigma, as far as I understood the paper.